# Updating application remotely on Windows 10

Tags: upgrade

For Windows (7/8/10) platform I am looking for an open source application upgrade library where it downloads the installer in the background and when it is complete triggers a fresh install procedure preferably completely in the background.

Skype, Chrome etc. does this type of thing to keep their apps up to date without any user interaction. I looked around but couldn't find a readily available library I can integrate with my application.

Comment: Although I think this is interesting it should probably better be moved to softwarerecs

Comment: @Marged I cannot find the site you refer to. Can you show me the link.

Comment: Try Google 'softwarerecs' or 'softwarerecs stack exchange'